# Validation of a tkinter entry box

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi this is my code so far

```
def Validate():
    if Entry1.get() == ('blue') or Entry1.get() ==  ('green') or Entry1.get() == ('brown'):
        window2=Tk()
        label2= Label(window2,text = 'Successful')
        label2.pack()
    else:
        window3=Tk()
        label3 = Label(window3,text = 'Failed')
        label3.pack()

Entry1 = Entry(window)
Entry1.pack()


label1 = Label(window, text = "Please enter colour")
label1.pack()

submitbutton = Button(window, text = "Submit")
submitbutton.pack()

submitbutton.configure(command=Validate)
```

This works but I want to try and get it so that if `'blue'`, `'Blue'` or `'BLUE'` was entered it would still be successful, any ideas?

I have used `NOCASE` in other aspects of my code to do with a database but I don't think it works in this case

Comment: Can you please fix your indentation?

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify `Validate`, try:

```
def Validate():
    if Entry1.get().lower() in ('blue', 'green', 'brown'):
        message = "Successful"
    else:
        message = "Failed"
    window = Tk()
    label = Label(window, text=message)
    label.pack()
```

This will lowercase the text for comparison to your acceptable values.

Comment: I would add a `.strip()` into the mix as well, to ignore any leading or trailing spaces.